# Entropy in organic chemistry

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Why do we not talk about entropy when deciding feasibility of an organic reaction?...We always seem to only be interested in stability of product and intermediate(essentially delta H)and draw their respective graphs of Delta H of the reaction showing the peak of intermediate..shouldn't we look at change in  Gibbs free energy for commenting on feasibility?

Comment: What do _you_ mean when you say "feasibility?"

Comment: Spontaneity .. regarding whether the reaction proceeds through a certain pathway here

Comment: You'd have to show an example of what you're talking about, but in my experience, reaction coordinate diagrams always have free energy on the vertical axis. We do provide bond dissociate enthalpies in tables, but that's because the entropic component is not easy to generalize.

Comment: I mean we only talk about relative stabilities (and not entropy )of various intermediates while deciding which pathway the reaction will follow..why is that?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by stabilities. If you're talking about stability as measured via a free energy, that is the most accurate way to do it, since free energy is a proxy for the total entropy change of the universe, which is the specific quantity that has restrictions based on the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: I actually mean stability in terms of intermediate stability on a high school level..like this carbocation is more stable or this resultant double bond is more stable

Comment: Unfortunately, the underlying chemistry does not change if you approach it from a high school level or not. The context is not the level but the particular effects you are trying to discuss. For the types of things you're talking about, the entropy effects are actually probably similar in the series, so bond enthalpies are generally what are looked at for simplicity.

Comment: Take a look at the second paragraph under the "Kinetic and thermodynamic considerations" section, at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_profile_(chemistry)

Comment: It's a bit like the story of the person who loses their keys at night and starts searching near a lantern where it is easy to see, even though the keys were lost somewhere else. Enthalpy changes are easier to estimate than entropy changes. Luckily, often Gibbs energy of reaction is dominated by the enthalpy change.

Comment: Why is the Gibbs energy of reaction dominated by enthalpy change?..or is this like a general experimental observation?